# Планировка интернет-магазина

Tags: php, mysql, интернет-магазин

Я в первый раз создаю интернет-магазин и я столкнулся с такой проблемой: как будет правильнее хранить данные о товарах и отображать их пользователю?

Пока придумал 2 варианта:

1. При создании товара админом, характеристики товара заносятся в базу данных и создается страничка самого товара .php
2. Каталог всех товаров генерируется каждый раз заново, с помощью инфы из БД.

2:

1. При создании товара админом, характеристики товара заносятся в базу данных
2. Каталог всех товаров *и сами страницы товаров* генерируется каждый раз заново, с помощью инфы из БД.

**Может быть есть более верный вариант хранения и отображения данных?**

Comment: Если мотивация задающего — «желание обсудить что-либо», то следует воздержаться от публикации такого вопроса. Обсуждения на любые темы, пересекающиеся с тематикой сайта, приветствуются в чате, но не на самом сайте вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Это не желание обсудить, а вопрос, на который я бы хотел получить ответ.

Comment: Смысл первого варианта до меня не доходит. В целом, я не очень понимаю, чем интернет-магазин принципиально отличается от любого другого сайта - форума, социальной сети, новостного сайта. Почему у интернет-магазина должен быть какой-то особый вариант хранения и отображения данных

Comment: @Ипатьев возможный смысл в том, что готовая страничка будет загружаться быстрее чем сгенерированная

Comment: "Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол". Распечатайте на листе бумаги А3 и повесьте перед рабочим местом.

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, вы сгенерили страницы под каждый товар. А теперь представьте, что у вас 500к товаров в базе лежит, у вас будет 500к готовых html страниц лежать?

Смотрите в сторону хранения в БД и получения данных из запроса. К примеру, человек обращается по адресу `/product/5`. В контроллере происходит следующее (самый банальный пример):

```
$product = Product::find($request->id);
return view('product.show', ['product' => $product]);
```

Где `view()` - это функция, которая рендерит html и возвращает его клиенту в качестве ответа сервера.